# Programmatically create a UINavigationController with a UICollectionViewController embed in a container

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, embed, containers

What I'd like to do is create a navigation controller based on a layout. Therefor I created a method `renderLayout` in my `UIStoryboard` class.

renderLayout:

```
UINavigationController *navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] init];
NSMutableArray *viewControllers = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

/* navigation bar styling */
// navigationController.toolbar.translucent = false;
// navigationController.title = @"TEST";

UIViewController *controller = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 1024, 768)];
UIScrollView *scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 1024, 768)];
scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(1024, /* some calculated value here */);

/* controller styling */
//controller.title = [page valueForKey:@"title"];

NSArray *items = /* ... */

int containerHeight = (1 + ([items count] / 3)) * 29;
MultiSelectionViewController *multiSelection = [[MultiSelectionViewController alloc] initWithItems:[data valueForKey:@"items"]];
multiSelection.view.frame = CGRectMake(20, 65, 984, containerHeight);
/* for debugging */
//multiSelection.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];

[scrollView addSubview:multiSelection.view];
[controller addChildViewController:multiSelection];
[multiSelection didMoveToParentViewController:controller];

[view addSubview:scrollView];
[controller.view addSubview:view];
[viewControllers addObject:controller];

[navigationController pushViewController:controller animated:true];
return navigationController;
```

The MultiSelection is a `UICollectionViewController<UICollectionViewDataSource>` kind of class that creates a collection of items which can be selected.

MultiSelectionViewController init method:

```
- (id)initWithItems:(NSArray*)items
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        self.items = items;

        UICollectionViewLayout *layout = [[UICollectionViewLayout alloc] init];
        self.view = [[UICollectionView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 0, 984, 29) collectionViewLayout:layout];

        self.collectionView.dataSource = self;
    }
    return self;
}
```

After a uses pushes a button on that current `UIViewController` the method gets called. It should then construct the navigation controller which I return and later load with

```
[self presentViewController:renderedNavController animated:true completion:^(){}];
```

So far everything is working quite well. The one problem I have is that It displays all kinds of labels and buttons and stuff that I can directly push onto the `scrollView` but it fails to load the `MultiSelection` elements. It displays a red rectangle in the size of the view frame but `viewDidLoad` never gets called inside the `MultiSelectionViewController`. Can someone help me with this? I've already done a lot of google research but couldn't find any solution yet.  I hope I explained my problem thoroughly, if not, ask away :)

Comment: Can you try swapping those lines please?
`[controller addChildViewController:multiSelection];[multiSelection didMoveToParentViewController:controller];[scrollView addSubview:multiSelection.view];` Btw, what does `viewControllers` do?

Comment: I tried that but it didn't resolve the problem. I also just checked that the `items` variable indeed as objects in it. I reduced my code a little, I'm actually repeating the middle part for different pages and elements and later add them all to the `navigationController ` (`for (UIViewController *controller in viewControllers)
        [navigationController pushViewController:controller animated:true];
    `)

Comment: Can you check in the `viewDidLoad` of `MultiSelectionViewController` if `self.view` has the right value?

Comment: the problem ist that `viewDidLoad` never gets called

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay I finally found the answer. In order to have the viewDidLoad method called I have to provide a layout and **init the view controller with it**.

Hence `self = [super init];` is wrong, the correct way to do it is `self = [super initWithCollectionViewLayout:layout`

On a side note, I had to use `UICollectionViewFlowLayout` (instead of `UICollectionViewLayout`) and use the method `setItemSize` to provide the correct size of the cells.